# SQL - Credit Debit and Balance

Tags: sql, absolute-db

I am using Delphi with Absolute Database (SQL92) i want to calculate in a SQL Query the following :

```
Year | Description | Credit | Debit | Balance
2016 | Car Service |    100 |     0 |      100
```

I want to search all customers where amount due is over 0 (>0) grouping by Year Customer and Description

I am using this script but i am geting the Amount Due with 0 also in the result :

```sql
SELECT 
SUM(CT1.CREDIT) AS "SUM_CREDIT", 
SUM(CT1.DEBIT) As "SUM_DEBIT", 
SUM(SUM(CT1.CREDIT)- SUM(CT1.DEBIT)) As Balance,
CT1.YearPay, CT1.IDCustomer, CT1.DescCredit

FROM "CustomersPayments" CT1 

GROUP BY CT1.YearPay, CT1.IDCustomer, CT1.DescCredit

HAVING (SUM(CT1.CREDIT) - SUM(CT1.DEBIT)) > 0

ORDER BY CT1.YearPay
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  SUM(CT1.CREDIT)          AS "SUM_CREDIT",
  SUM(CT1.DEBIT)           AS "SUM_DEBIT",
  (SUM_CREDIT - SUM_DEBIT) AS Balance,
  CT1.YearPay,
  CT1.IDCustomer,
  CT1.DescCredit
FROM "CustomersPayments" CT1
GROUP BY CT1.YearPay, CT1.IDCustomer, CT1.DescCredit
HAVING (SUM(CT1.CREDIT) - SUM(CT1.DEBIT)) > 0
ORDER BY CT1.YearPay
```

Comment: you should format the above code and give some explanations.